# macos, как полностью удалить vscode

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code

Как удалить vscode так, что бы, после скачивания и установки заново, не сохранялись прошлые настройки?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для того, чтобы удалить настройки не нужно удалять VSCode.

Выполните команду:

```
rm -Rf $HOME/.vscode*
```

Эта команда удалит папку с настройками VSCode.

Comment: Спасибо большое, очень помогли.